# Anybody planning to integrate NVIDIA's Isaac SDK with ROS?

Tags: ros, ros2, nvidia, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry if this isn't really answers.ros.org is for. Just curious if anybody is planning to implement this. I've had some experience implementing a Keras RL network with a ROS/MAVROS node but I wonder if Isaac might enable tighter integration with ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287104/anybody-planning-to-integrate-nvidia%27s-isaac-sdk-with-ros?/) by [crashtest84](https://answers.ros.org/users/32260/crashtest84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In 2020 IINM, [NVIDIA officially made ROS bridge for Isaac SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/building-collaborative-robotics-using-ros-and-isaac-sdk/).

I have yet used it so I can't tell anything. I couldn't find their release policy though, so far their release cycle doesn't seem rapid (release once or twice a year?). As of 2021/03/02 the latest version is still [2020.02 and runs on Ubuntu 18.04](https://docs.nvidia.com/isaac/isaac/packages/ros_bridge/doc/ros_bridge.html) (I'm not necessarily saying no frequent release is bad. It's just something to keep in mind).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2021-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-03**:
I've marked this as the answer (by accepting it), as this seems like it *is* the answer.

"Anybody" seems to be NVIDIA here, which, seeing as Isaac is NVIDIA's product, would be the ideal person/entity to provide that ROS wrapper.